# Should the circumstance for something that happens be decided before or afterwards?

Tags: terminology

Which is more approriate?

When event *E* happens, determined by *X,Y,Z*, *Input* is turned into *Output*.

Or

When event *E* happens, *Input* is turned into *Output*, determined by *X,Y,Z*.

Where determined by X,Y,Z represents the circumstance of the event *E*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question of English grammar for English SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you have in B is a dangling modifier, because the placement of the phrase 'determined by X,Y, and Z' might obfuscate your intended meaning.

I would offer a third option, and that is to modify the subject in the dependent clause instead of placing it in the main clause.

> When event E, **(which is) determined by X, Y, and Z**, happens, input is turned into output.

Comment: Ah amazing! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can trim it down too if you move the modifier out of the phrase... "When X, Y, and Z determine event E, input becomes output.". $0.02.

Comment: What do you think about replacing the term determine with "depending on"? So "When event E happens, depending on X,Y,Z, Input is transformed into Output"? In the sense of, depending on the time of day, the sun shines.

Comment: :D Sure. Just make sure whatever word you use properly reflects your views on [necessity and sufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency).

Comment: Your sentence! Do as you please. :D